# Laravel Vue Inertia need hard refresh for script asset in app.blade every change route

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have a script tag from CoreUI in my app.blade.php `<script src="{{ asset('js/coreui.js') }}" defer></script>` the problem is in every route page the script isn't being called thus not working the functions inside, I tried to require it in my app.js `require('./coreui')` but still doesn't work. To make it work I need to hard refresh the browser.

Comment: Did you try it without defer in script tag?

Comment: Yes, same results.

Comment: I have found the problem, it looks like the popper js stops working when the page changes routes, I'm using inertia-link for my routing.

Comment: Good. Add the solution so that others can use it

Comment: I haven't found a solution I just found the problem. All other JS functions works but the popper doesn't I'm using the bundled js cdn of core ui bootstrap 3.4.0

Comment: @kgcusi Any update on this. I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You provided a little bit of little information but try this:

`<script src="{{ mix('/js/coreui.js') }}" defer></script>`